# Update with results of Ordered Select into Column

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with four columns: `id | name | score | rank` that looks like this:

```
id | name | score | rank
---|------|-------|-----
1  | Bob  | 99    | -
2  | Jim  | 88    | -
3  | Rex  | 103   | -
4  | Zus  | 55    | -
```

I'd like to sort these rows by `score` (descending) and store the approriate ranking in the `rank` column for each row.

Currently, I'm using the following code to create an alias column that has the rankings:

```
SET @rank:=0;
SELECT *, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank_test FROM test ORDER BY score DESC
```

Which returns:

```
id | name | score | rank | rank_test
---|------|-------|------|----------
3  | Rex  | 103   | -    | 1
1  | Bob  | 99    | -    | 2
2  | Jim  | 88    | -    | 3
4  | Zus  | 55    | -    | 4
```

How can I transfer the result of the `rank_test` alias into the `rank` column?

I've researched a lot of answers but can't seem to get anything to work. Fairly new to SQL so I apologize if it's a simple solution. Thank you!

Comment: Why bother storing rank at all?

Comment: Storing rank would be incorrect as soon as your data changes or you add a new row. Just calculate the rank on the fly as you do now.

Comment: I figured that would be faster for when I need to calculate a user's rank later -- seems counterintuitive to re-sort the entire table to find one user's rank @Strawberry

Comment: Sometimes counter-intuition is the best kind.